# Correct endpoints for docker compose

Tags: spring, docker, docker-compose

I am new to docker compose and docker in general, so I am testing out a small example.

The problem I am trying to solve is how to have dynamic endpoints so that when I am running locally, http calls are made from my front-end to something like `localhost:8080/getPeople`, but when I am running these containers on digital ocean it goes to `myDomain:8080/getPeople`. I thought that was one of the main points in docker-compose and I am just missing something here. Here is my compose file.

```
version: '3'
services:
    main-backend:
        build: ./java-backend/backend
        volumes:
            - ./java-backend/backend:/usr/src/app
        ports: 
            - 8080:8080
    angular-frontend:
        image: mrich6347/my-frontend:1.04
        volumes: 
            - ./angular-frontend/my-frontend
        ports:
            - 80:80
        depends_on: 
            - main-backend
```

Comment: Use ENV variables https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

Comment: So you want your API on production to be different than your API on localhost or did I understand something wrong?

Comment: @LongNguyen when I run these applications locally, the endpoint in my spring backend will be reachable by localhost:8080, however when it is being run on my droplet in digitial ocean.. I have it running on a custom domain so the endpoint will be something like www.test.com:8080. So my question is how do I switch the endpoints when running local or in production without hard coding the endpoint URL's every time I switch

Comment: If I understood your Dockercompose file correctly, then your spring boot and your angular run on separate containers, so your angular should be able to reach spring boot via localhost if you intend to render your frontend on server-side, therefore there's no need to hard code the endpoint URL everytime you deploy your app. You however cann't reach the endpoint via localhost because it is obviously on a remote server. Did I understand it correctly?

Comment: @LongNguyen yes that is correct. I think I found what I was looking for which is the environment files within angular. If I am trying to reach my backend in production then I can run my angular app in production which will add a base url of my domain. Vice versa with locally. Thank you for the answers!

Comment: @matt what web server is running in the `mrich6347/my-frontend:1.04` image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a setup using a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) so that you can use relative url (instead of messing with domain names in your webpages) and which also has the advantage of taking care of [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) issues you would have while making ajax calls to your backend.

If you are not familiar with reverse proxies, just know that all http requests should first hit the reverse proxy, and the reverse proxy will take care of forwarding those http requests to the correct http server following a set of rules.

In the docker world, a very convenient reverse proxy is [Traefik](https://traefik.io/). Below is an example of docker compose project with a reverse proxy, frontend and backend:

**index.html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <h2>post a form to backend</h2>
    <form action="/api/post" method="post">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>ajax call to backend</h2>
    <button onclick="fetch('/api/json').then(response => response.text()).then(txt => document.getElementById('ajaxresponse').textContent = txt)">click me to make a ajax call to /api/json</button>
    <pre id="ajaxresponse"></pre>
</body>
</html>
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```
version: "3"
services:

  reverseproxy:  # see https://docs.traefik.io/#the-traefik-quickstart-using-docker
    image: traefik
    command: --docker
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

  backend:
    image: kennethreitz/httpbin # see https://httpbin.org
    command: ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8080", "httpbin:app", "-k", "gevent"]
    expose: 
      - 8080
    depends_on: 
      - reverseproxy
    labels:
      traefik.frontend.rule: PathPrefixStrip:/api
      traefik.port: 8080

  frontend:
    image: nginx
    volumes: 
      - ./index.html:/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html:ro
    expose:
      - 80
    depends_on: 
      - reverseproxy
      - backend
    labels:
      traefik.frontend.rule: PathPrefixStrip:/
      traefik.port: 80
```

When Traefik is used with docker, you configure for reverse proxy forwarding rules by adding [labels](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/backends/docker/#on-containers) to your docker containers.